# What is exactly meant by neural network that can take different types of input?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network

There is a scientific document that implements a convolutional neural network to classify **3 different types of data**, although how exactly, is unknown to me.

Here's the explanation of network architecture:

> This section describes architecture of our neural net which is
>   depicted in **Fig. 3.**
>   **Our network has three types of inputs**: **Screenshot** (we use upper crop of the page with dimensions 1280 × 1280, however this net can
>   work with arbitrarily sized pages), **TextMaps** (tensor with dimensions
>   $128 \times 160 \times 160$) and Candidate boxes (list of box coordinates of
>   arbitrary length).
>
> **A screenshot is processed by three convolutional layers** (the first two layers are initialized with pretrained weights from BVLC
>   AlexNet). **TextMaps are processed with one convolutional layer** with
>   kernel size $1 \times 1$ and thus its features capture various
>   combinations of words. These two layers are then concatenated and
>   processed by final convolutional layer.
>
> [image]

---

What exactly is implied by **Our network has three types of inputs** above? Is it possible for convolutional neural network to pass different types of inputs differently?

From my understanding, neural network for **Screenshot** input would be created like this:

```
def CNN(features, labels, mode):
  input_layer = tf.reshape(image, [-1, 1280, 1280, 1])

  # Conv+ReLU
  conv_relu_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=input_layer,
      filters=96,
      kernel_size=[11, 11],
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)

  # MaxPool
  pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[3, 3], strides=2)

  # Conv + ReLU
  ...
```

So let's say this is first neural network, then should I create another neural network for TextMaps and concatenate results? Or does every magic just happen in a single neural network?

**In short**, can I create neural network that takes different types of input individually or do I use different neural networks for each of them and then group their outputs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In short, can I create neural network that takes different types of
>   input individually or do I use different neural networks for each of
>   them and then group their outputs?

**Yes, you can.** Check the [Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) of Keras, on how to define multi input/output networks. Then you can create different models for the processing of each input and fuse them together into a single multi-input model using the `keras.models.Model()` class.

In the following example, you can see that the `main_input` is processed differently than the `aux_input` and both are thereafter merged together to be propagated through the rest of the layers of the network.

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, name "multi-input/output convultional neural network" seems to be a key word here. Are you aware of multi-input convolutional neural networks in raw tensorflow (or is it better to use high-level library for this purpose?).

Comment: Hi, to be honest I mostly work on a higher level with Keras and I strongly believe that you will find it quite easy to implement this kind of architecture in Keras, similarly to the attached image :)